# How can CPUs operate at such a low voltage with billions of transistors?

Tags: voltage, transistors, cpu

From what I understand, the voltage drop across a transistor is something like 0.5V and the minimum voltage for (conventional) current to pass from the emitter to the collector is 0.1-0.2V. If that is true, then how can CPUs operate at voltages as low as 1.5V if they have billions of transistors? Wouldn't current only get past the first 3 transistors?

Comment: Note that CPUs don’t run off BJTs but rather FETs

Comment: And all of those billions of transistors are not in series.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Would the difference between FET and BJT semiconductors be the answer to my question?

Comment: In MOSFET logic there is no sequential voltage drop, so you just need enough voltage to switch one transistor.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson there have got to be at least 3 in series somewhere though...

Comment: @user1850479 ok that makes sense. How do they achieve this?

Comment: Wikipedia might be a better place to start.

Comment: Yes, mosfets have rail-to-rail switching which means that the logic signal is fully regenerated after every switching stage (for the most part). BJT's can be used for logic also (and were before CMOS integrated circuit technology took over the whole world). The output signal just needs to have enough swing to satisfy the input stage. The drops don't add up through each sequential logic stage, depending on how you arrange the transistors.

Comment: It's the same way a key is so much easier to turn than the door is to open... the voltage is only used to **keep the blue smoke inside the CPU**, the pressure is great, but the transistors only need a little juice to hold it in.

Comment: @WeaselSqueezer, "keep the blue smoke inside the CPU"?? What is blue smoke? :D

Comment: The Blue smoke makes it work! Once the Blue smoke escapes it needs replacing.

Comment: Actually, there is no requirement for a digital device to have three or more transistors in series. Any logic circuit you can describe with a Boolean equation can be constructed entirely of 2-input NAND or NOR gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *less* important part of the answer is that in order to go fast and consume less power, CMOS chips use transistors designed to operate at very low voltages (by 1990 standards).

The *more* important part is that you are thinking of transistor arranged in series, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2nkHD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But in a modern CMOS chip, the transistors are in parallel -- actually series-parallel, but only short series strings.  Kind of like this.
It's common to have three or four in series, and some in parallel, but not more than that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOxLtY.png)</sup>

Search on "CMOS logic circuit" for more information.